# Delete Cache or Cookies in my Web browser Hiding mode

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, cookies, webbrowser-control

but it still show process of deleting.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Delete Cookies in my Web browser Hiding mode

    Dim prc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("Rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2")
    With psi
        .WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot")
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
    End With

    prc.StartInfo = psi
    prc.Start()

End Sub
```

Can i start that forum and delete cash with hiding mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code accurate work good, but problem is, impossible to hide Rundll32.exe